# How to use CSS with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using *PHP* to return data from my database and then using *javascript* to allow the person to add it. And I can't make a div change its background color and add borders etc.

```
<div class="selectedStuff"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#addButton').on('click', function( event ) {
        $('.selectedStuff').append($('#search_term').val() + '<br>'); 
   });          
</script>
<style type="text/css">
   .selectedStuff{
       background-color: yellow;
       margin-top: 50px;
   }
</style>
```

Any help on this matter would be great

Comment: Use the .css() methods on your divHolder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addButton').on('click', function( event ) {
                var searchedValue = $('#search_term').val(); 
                var divHolder = $('.selectedStuff'); 
                divHolder.append(searchedValue + '<br>').css({
                    'background-color': 'yellow',
                    'margin-top': '50px'
               }); 
           });
```

Comment: Ye just spotted it :0 perfect x

Comment: Why would you replace perfectly good CSS with the old-fashioned jQuery approach of applying styles directly to elements? Why doesn't the OP's CSS work?